# Consuming a Web Service using https in .NET

Tags: c#, web-services

I am consuming a web service from https://www.abc.com/def.asmx?WSDL. This is HTTPS. How can I consume a web service using HTTPS from a .NET client. Note: I am already consuming this web service over http. What additional steps do I need to take to make it secure. I am passing in username and password in SOAP header. What extra steps do I need to take.

Comment: That should be it... https should signal to use a secure connection instead of plain text

Comment: No extra steps are necessary other than changing `http://` to `https://` in the url.

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/ and many other places. There is nothing special to do.

Comment: Thanks everybody. That does it!

Answer (score 1):

There are no additional steps you need to do except for when you are consuming that web service make sure that you point it to a https:// url vs a http:// Should be as simple as adding a new web reference and pointing to that https url.